# Group of order 63

Tags: abstract-algebra

I googled my question, nothing appeared. My book says that group of order 63 is Abelian. The way I see it is perfectly possible that it has 7 Sylow 3 subgroups and one Sylow 7 subgroup. Please help!

Comment: it is a group of order $p^2q$

Comment: Note that "group of order $63$" may imply Abelian without necessarily requiring all such groups to be isomorphic.

Comment: $\mathbb{Z}_7\rtimes \mathbb{Z}_9$ and $\mathbb{Z}_7\rtimes (\mathbb{Z}_3\times\mathbb{Z}_3)$ are non-abelian groups of order $63$.

Answer (score 1):

If that is the case, what are the (maximal) numbers of elements of orders

1. is either $3$ or $9$?
2. is equal to $7$?

Answer (score 1):

I'll try to write an answer describing groups of order $63=3^2\cdot7$.

(If there is any mistake please let me know)

It is $n_7|9,\ n_7\equiv 1\pmod7\Rightarrow n_7=1$ so there is a unique Sylow $7-$subgroup $P_7\lhd G$.

It is also $n_3|7,\ n_3\equiv 1\pmod3\Rightarrow n_3=1,7$. Let $P_3$ be a Sylow $3-$subgroup. It is $P_3=9$ so $P_3\cong \mathbb{Z}_9$ or $\mathbb{Z}_3\times\mathbb{Z}_3$

- If $n_3=1$ then $P_3\lhd G$ and $|P_3P_7|=|G|$ with $P_3P_7\leq G$ hence $G=P_3\times P_7\cong \mathbb{Z}_9\times \mathbb{Z}_7$ or $\mathbb{Z}_3\times \mathbb{Z}_3\times \mathbb{Z}_7$.
- If $n_3=7$ it is $G=P_7\rtimes_{\phi}P_3$ where $\phi:P_3\to Aut(P_7)$. Since $P_3\not\lhd G$ it follows that $\phi$ is non-trivial. Hence (since $Aut(\mathbb{Z}_7)\cong \mathbb{Z}_6$) $\phi$ maps $P_3$ to the unique subgroup of $\mathbb{Z}_6$ of order $3$. So $G\cong \mathbb{Z}_7\rtimes_{\phi}\mathbb{Z}_9$ or $G\cong \mathbb{Z}_7\rtimes_{\phi}[\mathbb{Z}_3\times \mathbb{Z}_3]$.

In the first case $\phi:P_3=\langle x\rangle \to Aut(P_7)=\mathbb{Z}_6=\langle \tau\rangle,\phi(x)=\tau,\ \tau(a)=a^2$ and in the second case $\phi:\langle x\rangle\times\langle y\rangle\to Aut(P_7)=\mathbb{Z}_6=\langle \tau\rangle,\ \phi(x)=\tau,\phi(y)=1,\tau(a)=a^2$

Comment: You might want to say more about the last case in your answer: the reason you only get one isomorphism class is because your Sylow 3-group is completely reducible: the kernel of $\phi$ has a complement.

Comment: @Steve D Thanks for the comment. I thought it was obvious by the symmetry of $x,y$ but I'll try to see what you mean

Comment: Well I can define a new $\tilde{\phi}$ with $\tilde{\phi}(x)=\tilde{\phi}(y)=\tau$. But the semidirect product I get is isomorphic to yours.

Comment: @Steve D So if I understand correctly you say that $P_3=ker\phi\times Q$ and this gives me the fact that the two groups are isomorphic, but I can't see why. Let me think for a bit

Comment: Since $f:\langle x\rangle \times \langle y\rangle \to \langle x\rangle \times \langle y\rangle$ with $f(x)=y,f(y)=x$ is an automoprhism of $P_3$ I think that this is enough to explain why the semidirect products $P_7 \rtimes_{\phi} P_3,\ P_7 \rtimes_{\phi\circ f} P_3$ are isomorphic. I try to see whether this works for your $\bar{\phi}$

Comment: @Steve D I think that $f: \langle x\rangle \times \langle y\rangle \to \langle x\langle \times \langle y\rangle$ with $f(x)=x,f(y)=yx$ is an isomorphism and $\phi\circ f=$ yours $\bar{\phi}$. What do you think?

Comment: Looks good${}{}$.